# Operator overloading errors for a simple 3x3 matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

So I have this as my class.cpp File

```
#include "matrixType3.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void matrixType3::setElement(int row, int col, int newvalue)
{
    matrix[row][col] = newvalue;
}

double matrixType3::getElement(int row, int col)
{
    int j = matrix[row][col];
    return j;
}

void matrixType3::setMatrix(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6, int x7, int x8, int x9)
{
    matrix[0][0] = x1;
    matrix[0][1] = x2;
    matrix[0][2] = x3;
    matrix[1][0] = x4;
    matrix[1][1] = x5;
    matrix[1][2] = x6;
    matrix[2][0] = x7;
    matrix[2][1] = x8;
    matrix[2][2] = x9;
}

void matrixType3::display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][r] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void matrixType3::displayRow(int row)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << matrix[row][i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void matrixType3::displayColumn(int col)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][col] << endl;
    }
}

void matrixType3::multipleMatrix(int c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            int j = matrix[i][r];
            matrix[i][r] = j * c;
        }
    }
}

matrixType3 matrixType3::operator=(const matrixType3&mat) const
{
    matrixType3 tempMatrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            tempMatrix.matrix[i][r] = mat.matrix[i][r];
        }
    }
    return tempMatrix;
}

matrixType3 matrixType3::operator+(const matrixType3& mat) const
{
    matrixType3 tempMatrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            tempMatrix.matrix[i][r] = mat.matrix[i][r] + matrix[i][r];
        }
    }
    return tempMatrix;
}

matrixType3 matrixType3::operator-(const matrixType3& mat) const
{
    matrixType3 tempMatrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            tempMatrix.matrix[i][r] = matrix[i][r] - mat.matrix[i][r];
        }
    }
    return tempMatrix;
}

matrixType3 matrixType3::operator*(const matrixType3& mat) const
{
    matrixType3 tempMatrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                tempMatrix.matrix[i][r] = tempMatrix.matrix[i][r] + matrix[i][k] * mat.matrix[k][r];
            }
        }
    }
    return tempMatrix;
}

matrixType3 matrixType3::operator*(const int&num) const
{
    matrixType3 tempMatrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            tempMatrix.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] * num;
        }
    }
    return tempMatrix;
}

bool matrixType3::operator==(const matrixType3& mat) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][r] != mat.matrix[i][r])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

matrixType3::matrixType3()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            matrix[i][c] = 0;
        }
    }
}

matrixType3::matrixType3(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6, int x7, int x8, int x9)
{
    matrix[0][0] = x1;
    matrix[0][1] = x2;
    matrix[0][2] = x3;
    matrix[1][0] = x4;
    matrix[1][1] = x5;
    matrix[1][2] = x6;
    matrix[2][0] = x7;
    matrix[2][1] = x8;
    matrix[2][2] = x9;
}

matrixType3::~matrixType3()
{

}
```

However, my issue is that the operator overload functions are not working. The source.cpp File runs for all the other member functions except all of the operator overload functions. I am wondering if anyone can see what is wrong with this code? Since when I try C = A * B it just returns the constructed c matrix of 0s in a three by three matrix. 
The class is just supposed to take a 3x3 matrix and edit it. 
The operator overloads are for +,-,*, ==, and =. 
As a side note the complier is showing no errors but the overload functions are not working.

Comment: Your assignment operator looks very unusual. The usual signature should be `matrixType3& matrixType3::operator=(const matrixType3 &other)`. It shouldn't be `const` nor return a `const` reference. It should assign values of `other` to members of `*this` and return `*this`. (The 2nd flavor could be a move assignment operator.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the OP didn't provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Hence, I copy/pasted parts of OP's code which were IMHO OK (and not the reason of the reported issue) and did the rest by myself.

This is the sample I prepared:

```
#include <iostream>

class matrixType3 {

  private:
    int matrix[3][3];

  public:
    matrixType3(): matrix{ 0 } { }

    matrixType3(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6, int x7, int x8, int x9):
      matrix{ { x1, x4, x7 }, { x2, x5, x8 }, { x3, x6, x9 } }
    { }

    ~matrixType3() = default;

    matrixType3(const matrixType3&) = default;

#if 0 // OP's version:
    matrixType3 operator=(const matrixType3&mat) const
    {
      std::cout << "matrixType3 matrixType3::operator=(const matrixType3 &mat)()\n";
      matrixType3 tempMatrix;
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
          tempMatrix.matrix[i][r] = mat.matrix[i][r];
        }
      }
      return tempMatrix;
    }
#else // My version:
    /* This would be actually sufficient:
    matrixType3& operator=(const matrixType3&) = default;
     * but for demonstration a custom implementation:
     */
    matrixType3& operator=(const matrixType3 &mat)
    {
      std::cout << "matrixType3& operator=(const matrixType3 &mat)()\n";
      std::copy(
        std::begin(mat.matrix[0]), std::end(mat.matrix[0]),
        std::begin(matrix[0]));
      std::copy(
        std::begin(mat.matrix[1]), std::end(mat.matrix[1]),
        std::begin(matrix[1]));
      std::copy(
        std::begin(mat.matrix[2]), std::end(mat.matrix[2]),
        std::begin(matrix[2]));
      return *this;
    }
#endif // 0

    // copy/pasted from OP:
    matrixType3 operator+(const matrixType3& mat) const
    {
      matrixType3 tempMatrix;
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
          tempMatrix.matrix[i][r] = mat.matrix[i][r] + matrix[i][r];
        }
      }
      return tempMatrix;
    }

    /* a "getter" to provide read-only access to the member variable
     *
     * (Returning a const reference to a 2d array makes this function
     *a bit strange looking...) ;-)
     */
    const int (&get() const)[3][3] { return matrix; }
};
```

The OP claimed that

> However, my issue is that the operator overload functions are not working.

I strongly believe that exactly OP's `operator=()` is the problem where the other operators look not that bad. The signature chosen by OP for `operator=` looks very unusual to me.
It should be instead:

```
matrixType3& operator=(const matrixType3 &mat)
```

The operator should assign argument `mat` to itself (i.e. `*this`). Hence, it may not be `const` and shouldn't return a `const` reference. (The latter would probably work but would constrain applicability of return value unnecessarily.)

To prove that I'm on the right track, I copy/pasted OP's `operator=()` into my sample code and observed exactly what OP described.

Btw. I put an output statement into the assignment operator just to show when it is called.

To check the above code, the rest of sample:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const matrixType3 &mat)
{
  const int (&values)[3][3] = mat.get();
  return out
    << values[0][0] << '\t' << values[0][1] << '\t' << values[0][2] << '\n'
    << values[1][0] << '\t' << values[1][1] << '\t' << values[1][2] << '\n'
    << values[2][0] << '\t' << values[2][1] << '\t' << values[2][2] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  matrixType3 mat1(11, 21, 31, 12, 22, 32, 13, 23, 33);
  std::cout << "mat1:\n" << mat1;
  matrixType3 mat2;
  std::cout << "mat2:\n" << mat2;
  std::cout << "mat2 = mat1;\n";
  mat2 = mat1;
  std::cout << "mat2:\n" << mat2;
  std::cout << "mat1 + mat2:\n" << mat1 + mat2;
  matrixType3 mat3;
  mat3 = mat1 + mat2;
  std::cout << "mat3 = mat1 + mat2:\n" << mat3;
  // This is no assigment:
  std::cout << "No assignment: matrixType3 mat4 = mat1;\n";
  matrixType3 mat4 = mat1;
  std::cout << "... but initialization/copy construction\n";
  std::cout << "mat4:\n" << mat4;  
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested (with my `operator=()`):

```
mat1:
11  12  13
21  22  23
31  32  33
mat2:
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
mat2 = mat1;
matrixType3& operator=(const matrixType3 &mat)()
mat2:
11  12  13
21  22  23
31  32  33
mat1 + mat2:
22  24  26
42  44  46
62  64  66
matrixType3& operator=(const matrixType3 &mat)()
mat3 = mat1 + mat2:
22  24  26
42  44  46
62  64  66
No assignment: matrixType3 mat4 = mat1;
... but initialization/copy construction
mat4:
11  12  13
21  22  23
31  32  33
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/562c0ecbc12e257d)</kbd>

While preparing the sample code, I stumbled over:

```
matrixType3 mat1;
matrixType3 mat2; mat2 = mat1;
```

vs.

```
matrixType3 mat1;
matrixType3 mat2 = mat1;
```

which I found worth to elaborate as well.

Although both samples are looking very similar, there is big difference:
the 1<sup>st</sup> uses copy assignment but in the 2<sup>nd</sup> the `=` is compiled as initialization (because following directly the declaration). Hence, in the 2<sup>nd</sup> case, there is no assingment. (Instead, the copy constructor is called.)